# 'The fact that' versus just 'That'

Tags: writing-style

Recently, I started using just 'That' instead of 'The fact that' at the beginning of some sentences. What is your opinion on this?

Example:

> 1. The fact that he answered the question wrong shows...
> 2. That he answered the question wrong shows ...

What is better style? 1 or 2?

Comment: This is not related to your actual question, but there actually should not be a comma in either of those two sentences.

Comment: Related: [“Reflects that” versus “reflects the fact that”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84397/reflects-that-versus-reflects-the-fact-that)

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I like 2 better in writing, although both are possible. In spoken language, I would only use 1. One often hears "the fact that" vilified as being redundant, mostly because Strunk & White say it's never acceptable. It's true that it is often used unnecessarily to inflate a writer's style. However, it's not always inappropriate:

> The police confronted him with the fact that he hadn't been where he said he was.

Comment: I don't know how you'd phrase your sample sentence without using "the fact that", barring a considerable recasting.

Comment: @siride, that was my point. It's _not_ always inappropriate, because any other way of writing that example sentence would be awkward.

Comment: @ptomata: sorry, I misread that as "not always appropriate".

Comment: It's been a loooong time since this question was answered, but I wanted to know why both are acceptable/grammatical. If you could explain, that'd be great.

Comment: Good question - I'm not sure I can give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the "the fact" doesn't add to the sentence, remove it.